# 302 Redirect set by Magento, 9300 Crawling errors

Tags: magento, redirect, seo, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

I have a SEOMOZ Pro account, and after crawling we have 9300 Warnings, and 90% of them are because of 302 redirect errors.
It looks like its something with the compare feature.

URL: 
http://goo.gl/Dg1jY

0 Errors

No errors found!
1 Warning

302 (Temporary Redirect)
Found 1 day ago
Redirects to
http://goo.gl/OcAqw
Description
Using a 302 redirect will cause search engine crawlers to treat the redirect as temporary and not pass any link juice (ranking power). We highly recommend that you replace 302 redirects with 301 redirects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Yoast Canonical](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/canonical-url-for-magento.html) extension should fix that for you. It sets a canonical URL for the compare URLs that point to the actual Product page.

Comment: I wonder if there is another solution, I have seo enterprise suite from mageworx and I wouldnt like to install 2 SEO extensions.

Comment: hmm, reading the description of the MageWorx extension, it should already be doing the canonical URLs, so perhaps its not configured correctly or something else is interfering with it?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. You can change whether or not you want to redirect cookie-less users to "enable cookies" page, in `System -> Configuration -> Web -> Browser capabilities detection -> Redirect to CMS-page if Cookies are Disabled`

I disabled it, and then changed the source code (version 1.7.0.2) as follows:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php
93c93
<     public function setRedirect($url, $code = 302)
---
>     public function setRedirect($url, $code = 301)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've only got 1 store view, then consider disabling "Use SID on front end" - this should help some of your natural links considerable.

Canonical URLs are in the core from version 1.4 onwards - so don't install a 3rd party extension.

Also, consider disabling HTTPS on non-checkout/account pages - you are slowing down your site unnecessarily.

As a side note, you're missing a favicon and showing full server tokens ;)

Comment: how can I disable https on non checkout pages?

Comment: HTTPS is not enabled on non-checkout pages (other than customer my account).